# Do we have lower performance and accuracy than when not using `pytorch.nn.Sequnetial` and if yes, why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I was checking out [this](https://youtu.be/hlv79rcHws0?t=1731) video where Phil points out to this fact that using `torch.nn.Sequential` is faster than not using it. I did quick google and came across [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-use-sequential-or-not-will-have-different-performance/7129) post which is not answered satisfactorily, so I am replicating it here.

Here is the code from the post with `Sequential`:

```
class net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net2, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1,
                out_channels=16,
                kernel_size=5,
                stride=1,
                padding=2,
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
        )
        self.out = nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        output = self.out(x)
        return output
```

And here is the net without `Sequential`:

```
class net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net1, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,16,5,1,2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16,32,5,1,2)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*7*7,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        out = self.pool1(out)
        out = F.relu(self.conv2(out))
        out = self.pool2(out)

        out = out.view(-1,32*7*7)
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
        return out
```

In the comment, the author also states that the accuracy is better with `Sequential` than without it. One of the comment states that speed is more with `Sequential` because [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) results in faster execution. So here are my related questions:

1. Is loop unrolling only reason why `Sequntial` implementation faster than the other one?
2. Can someone explain how non-`Sequential` does not result in loop unrolling and `Sequntial` results in loop-unrolling, perhaps by pointing me to [pytorch source lines on github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch)
3. Does `Sequential` really result in more accuracy, if yes why?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with what kind of optimizations the python interpreter does, but I'd guess it is very limited.

But the claim that one method is more accurate than another is completely nonsense. If you look at the implementation of [nn.Sequential](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/container.html#Sequential) you'll see that it does exactly the same thing you'd do anyway, you just iterate over the modules and pass the output of one to the input of the next:

```
def forward(self, input):
    for module in self:
        input = module(input)
    return input
```

There might be a tiny difference in speed due to the overhead of all the additional things that `nn.Sequential` might do, but this is negligible.

Comment: As pointed out by Berriel, the two code arent exactly same which explains different accuracy. Slide 8 (or pdf page 10) of [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs245/win2020/slides/09-PyTorch.pdf) slide, states various performance improvement done by pytorch. But unable to find related details for this question.

Comment: @Mahesha999 These slides are very vagues and not part of the documentation, so I would only trust the official sources.

Answer (score 2):

Note that these 2 architectures are **different**. One has a ReLU right before the output (`net1`, `F.relu(self.fc1(out))`) and the other doesn't (`net2`, `self.out(x)`). This might explain why one has a different accuracy than the other.

With regards to speed, I don't think there should be any difference. ReLU is often negligible w.r.t. speed. Given that you didn't state the speed difference, it is difficult to say what could be the reason.

Comment: Ahhh... that must be the mistake in pytorch post ... So at least accuracy should be the same.  Slide 8 (or pdf page 10) of [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs245/win2020/slides/09-PyTorch.pdf) slide, states various performance improvement done by pytorch. But unable to find related details for this question.

Comment: @Mahesha999 those are benefits/improvements of the script mode, such as when you run using PyTorch JIT. Consider upvoting if you find this answer useful.